# Our house is full of termite infected

Tags: termite

Our house is full of termite infected. We drilled and put holes on each wall and put the termite solution which the seller guarantee for 5 years. Later constructed a modular kitchen in wood which was totally eaten by termite.

what actions should be taken to stop termite on old buildings ?
is destroying and constructing a new building is the only option?

currently we are changing the doors and others to plastic and pvc doors

any good and workable solution is helpful

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't say destroying the structure is necessary, but exposing the structure/gutting it is probably going to be needed. Also, do other homes or wooden structures nearby have termites? you will want to eradicate the sources of reinfection. Also, call a professional exterminator, do not just do it yourself if your problem is as severe as you imply. Note, there are termites that eat dry wood, and others that eat wet wood. Find out what species you have. If they are wet based, it is possible you can solve it.

Comment: It is wet based but spread throughout the building. professional spray a white colour liquid by putting holes on several places but it is not helpful...it still eats it..

Comment: The species of termite you have is confirmed to be one that eats wet wood? If so then you will have to correct the source of water then begin gutting and repairing. It does not necessarily matter that the product you bought is one that professionals use. You've expressed a problem that is getting worse or coming back, therefore you have not succeeded in self remedy. Considering a home can typically cost us 1-5 years salary, it should stand to reason that $100-200 per sq foot rebuild cost is enough to invest in a professional at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Stop self treating the property at this point with the expectation of solving the issue. It has not worked and frankly time is your enemy (just as much as the termites are)
2. The more time that elapses, the more money it will cost
3. Drilling holes in a termite infected are is no certain guarantee to kill the total infestation.
4. Hire a professional Exterminator
5. Hire a professional contractor
6. Remove all affected/infected and damaged wood
7. Correct any entry points of water damage
8. If money and do it yourself savings is something you are interested in, then invest the time in removing personal belongings, various fixtures, and prep work the contractor and exterminator suggest be done. The more you are able to salvage *(if that is your goal), the more you could possibly re-use
9. Work as a team with your municipality, contractors, family, etc....
10. It is possible that the structure is beyond repair, i.e. to be condemned. Again, work with professionals to determine this.

Again, it is not good news, but the more time termites have to work, the more damage they can do. There comes a point your life is at risk.

If the property is NOT as bad as it sounds from what you have said, then steps 1-9 are all still applicable. Your time and money will be better spent in this capacity.

Answer (score 0):

One can hire a professional to fumigate with 'Vikane', however before resorting to this expensive and inconvenient method it may make sense to professionally spot treat with Termidor (active ingredient [fipronil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fipronil)).

Fipronil is brought back from the workers and delivered to others in the colony ('transfer effect') and remains well after it is sprayed.  Vikane gas is temporary and dissipates: its advantage is that it has greater (albeit temporary reach).

IMHO, I would remove conditions that promote termites and try the Fipronil.   Carefully monitor: if this does not resolve the infestation then use the 'big guns' and fumigate with Vikane gas.

Good luck and please update with actions taken and lessons-learned